# What is the optimal way to calculate tax: apply tax to each item, then sum the prices, or sum the prices, then apply tax? When are prices rounded?

Tags: united-states, taxes, calculation, sales-tax

What is the optimal way to calculate tax?

Lets say tax is 7.5% or 0.075.

```
$2.32 X 1.075 = 2.494 --> Rounded: $2.50
```

You can say that item is $2.50 (tax included)

and if you have two items:

```
$2.32 X 1.075 = 2.494 --> Rounded: $2.50
$2.55 X 1.075 = 2.74125 --> Rounded: $2.75

Total will be $5.25
```

But this doesn't hold true if you round after adding the items.

```
$2.32 + $2.55 = $4.87
$4.87 X 1.075 = 5.23525 -> Rounded: $5.24
```

Which way is correct? How do some stores say that all items include tax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either way is correct. The difference is simply due to rounding error; usually, 2.74125 rounds to 2.74, not 2.75.

Mathematically, these methods are clearly equivalent:

[image: p1*t + p2*t = t*(p1+p2)]

where `t` is the gross tax rate. The left-hand side is the first method, and the right-hand side is the second method.

In the US, stores usually display prices *without* sales tax included. When you pay for the items, the prices are totaled and sales tax is applied to the total price of your items (or the items in that sales tax bracket, since different items can have different amounts of sales tax).

Some stores display prices with the sales tax included; in this case, they've applied the tax to each item separately and used that value as the display price. Mathematically, these methods are *identical*, so it doesn't matter which one they use. The price you pay is the same.

Comment: I guess my question is which rounding method is better? And which one do stores use?

Comment: @Arian Mathematically, these methods are **identical.** I believe stores usually use the second method, though, assuming prices are displayed *without* sales tax included; they sum the prices, then apply sales tax.

Comment: @Arian state laws may dictate which methods to use. Example: http://www.boe.ca.gov/sutax/faqreport.htm#7 .

Comment: @littleadv That's referring to the rounding method, though, not the order in which sales tax is applied (I might be missing where in that link it specifies the order in which tax is applied).

Comment: Oh, I was talking about the rounding method. The tax is always applied on the total taxable amount per invoice.

Comment: @littleadv That's for whole dollars... we are talking about the .005 rounding, and when do you perform rounding?

Comment: @Arian that's for the sales tax return, I'm giving it as an example that state law may define the rounding method.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Thanks, and thanks for the edit to correct my silly yet important mistake.

Comment: -1 This answer suggests, *wrongly*, that the two methods are identical and it doesn't matter. Obviously, it does matter, and OP even demonstrated clearly the reason and need for the question. If it weren't for the 1 sentence in the middle that includes "sales tax is applied to the total" I would even say this doesn't answer the question. The methods are *NOT IDENTICAL*. Even mathematically, there is such a thing as integer math (which is what applies in Q: integer cents), and in it your formula proof is incorrect; the axiom you are making use of only holds for real numbers.

Comment: However, we should ask ourselves if this is even how it works; perhaps numbers are recorded out to the nearest tenth of a cent, meaning a rounding difference is still possible but is less likely. I do not know how it is done, and I do not know if the government cares or if they leave it up to the shop to decide. These would make good further questions.

Comment: Sorry if my comments read as harsh; it's not my intention. Just trying to point out the facts.

Answer (score 4):

The procedure for rounding for sales tax is dictated by state law. Even if there are city sales taxes, it is generally governed by state law. Most jurisdictions dictate that the subtotal by tax type is done, then the rate applied. Never expect that the rounding will be down.

The places that say they include sales tax in the prices are doing it to make their transactions easier. They round up all the prices to the nearest quarter and they never have to worry about giving pennies, nickles or dimes as change. You frequently see this at sport stadiums, boardwalks, ice cream trucks, and movie theaters. They expect to do a lot of cash transactions, and the purchaser may be a child.

They may also be working without a computerized cash register, and including the taxes in the price doesn't slow down the process when they need to total the prices for each customer.

Answer (score 1):

My math differs

```
$2.55 X 1.075 = 2.74125 --> Rounded: $2.75
```

I round 2.74125 to 2.74. Why are you rounding up if it's less than half point? Usually, amounts are [rounded half-up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up).

In fact, in your example you would be better off rounding separately:

2.494 is rounded to 2.49, 2.74125 rounded to 2.74, end result is 5.23.

Comment: Oh, the way I thought money rounding work was always round up... so .0000001 is .01

Comment: No. Why? That wouldn't be fair and mathematically incorrect.

Comment: Because the store is losing the .00125 when you round at half-up

Comment: Or gains. It averages out in the global scope of things. And its not the store, its the state. The store doesn't keep these taxes.